# Grails(spring-amqp) - connecting with RabbitMQ with SSL through XML configuration

Tags: xml, ssl, grails, config, spring-amqp

I've been trying to modify configuration of an old project(that is based on grails 2.5.6) to use ssl connection when integrating with RabbitMQ instance. I have spring-amqp in version 1.4.6. My old version of config is written in a xml file like this:

```
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit-1.4.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<rabbit:connection-factory
        id="connectionFactory"
        username="guest2"
        password="guest"
        virtual-host="dev"
        host="localhost"
        port="5672"
/>
```

I also have listeners configured like this:

```
<bean id="rabbitListener" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="queues" ref="rabbitQueue" />
    <property name="defaultRequeueRejected" value="false"/>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="listenerService" />
    <property name="errorHandler" ref="errorHandlerService" />
    <property name="autoStartup" value="false" />
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1" />
</bean>
```

I've set up rabbitmq server so it has available ssl connection at port 5671. Then based on documentation i've found here: [spring-documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/htmlsingle/#_rabbitconnectionfactorybean_and_configuring_ssl), i've modified xml config like this:

```
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit-1.4.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<rabbit:connection-factory
        id="connectionFactory"
        connection-factory="clientConnectionFactory"
        username="guest2"
        password="guest"
        virtual-host="dev"
        host="localhost"
        port="5671"
/>

<bean id="clientConnectionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.xd.dirt.integration.rabbit.RabbitConnectionFactoryBean">
    <property name="useSSL" value="true" />
    <property name="sslPropertiesLocation" value="file://./rabbitSSL.properties"/>
</bean>
```

With that configuration when running application i get errors looking like this:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitListener' defined in URL [file:/target/classes/rabbitmq/resources-listeners.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'connectionFactory' while setting bean property 'connectionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'connectionFactory': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#50b63731' of type [org.springframework.xd.dirt.integration.rabbit.RabbitConnectionFactoryBean] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#50b63731': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: .
```

---

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#50b63731': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: .
```

I've been struggling with this issue. I'm not sure how to interpret this error and how to solve it. Has anyone encountered similiar issue or might have a clue what might be wrong with this configuration ?

Comment: Why are you using a class from Spring XD here? There is a `RabbitConnectionFactoryBean` in the spring-rabbit jar. Turn on DEBUG logging to see it it helps - even better, upgrade to at least 1.7.5 where we added some diagnostics when connecting.

Comment: I've tried already using 
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitConnectionFactoryBean,
but i get exactly same error. When I upgraded to 1.7.5.RELEASE I get different error:
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.config.internalCacheAdvisor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableBeanFactory.getSingletonMutex()Ljava/lang/Object;

Comment: 1.7.5 requires a newer version of spring-framework jars (4.3.13)

Comment: I've been playing with dependencies and added `spring-core:4.3.13`. After that I'm still geting same error. I'm using `grails 2.5.6` (I can't go any higher than that because of other plugins dependencies), which is built upon `spring 4.1.9`. As i see it i think i'm getting doubled jar's with different versions and I suspect that wrong one is applied. I don't know if it is possible to work like that. It looks that with `grails 2.5.6` i can only go as far as `spring-rabbit:1.4.6` since higher versions require spring versions higher than `4.1.9`(which i'm stuck with).

Comment: I've enabled Debug logging, but i'm back to square one. Here are some relevant logs with error i get: http://textuploader.com/dh4i6

Comment: `> UnknownHostException` At this point, I think you'll need to run in a debugger; set a breakpoint in `AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection()` to figure out exactly what host it's connecting to. As you can see in that class all the other properties are simply passed into the underlying rabbit connection factory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a late reply but i've found the issue. It was my fault all along. After debugging i've found that `sslPropertiesLocation` was set incorrectly. Double `/` in `file://./rabbit..` made it go for incorrect ftp location. After setting proper file location like: `file:grails-app/conf/rabbit/file` connection got set up. The debug suggestion made me realize my mistake. Thanks a lot.